# Flutter getx ui not fully build issue on loading --release version

Tags: android, flutter, get, flutter-getx

everyone, I am having an issue with the release version of the flutter app where I do get everything perfect when the apps load for the first time after installing but after exiting it and re-opening the app gives an issue with the Ui build.
[This is the expected result and as I get it for the first time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDbem.png)

[This is what I get from the second time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am2tJ.png)

Key points I noticed:

- I think it has something to do with getX and get controller as I didn't get any errors before using get and recent apps I have to build using getx throwing similar errors.
- When I reopen the app after some time it works then again after exiting it won't, it is a continuous process.
- I am using get and separating the view, controller and bindings.

Here is my main.dart file, login_binding.dart file, login_controller.dart file and login_view.dart file respectively.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

import 'package:travel_mate/app/utils/my_translations.dart';

import 'package:travel_mate/app/utils/themes.dart';

import 'app/modules/Bindings/login_binding.dart';
import 'app/routes/app_pages.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await GetStorage().initStorage;

  runApp(
    Sizer(
      builder: (BuildContext context, Orientation orientation,
          DeviceType deviceType) {
        var isDark = GetStorage().read('isDark');
        return GetMaterialApp(
          defaultTransition: Transition.cupertino,
          translations: MyTranslations(),
          locale: Locale('en'),
          fallbackLocale: Locale('np'),
          themeMode: isDark != null
              ? isDark
                  ? ThemeMode.dark
                  : ThemeMode.light
              : ThemeMode.system,
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: "Application",
          getPages: AppPages.routes,
          initialRoute: GetStorage().read('token') != null
              ? AppPages.INITIAL
              : AppPages.SECONDARY,
          theme: lightTheme,
          darkTheme: darkTheme,
          initialBinding: LoginBinding(),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:travel_mate/app/modules/Controller/auth_controller.dart';
import 'package:travel_mate/app/modules/Controller/login_controller.dart';

class LoginBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.put(LoginController());
    Get.put(AuthController());
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
import 'package:travel_mate/app/models/user.dart';
import 'package:travel_mate/app/modules/Controller/auth_controller.dart';
import 'package:travel_mate/app/modules/views/tab/tab_view.dart';

class LoginController extends GetxController {
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey();
  TextEditingController emailOrUsernameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  var isLoading = false.obs;
  Rx<User?>? user;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    emailOrUsernameController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
  }

  final count = 0.obs;

  void increment() => count.value++;

  void login() async {
    if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      isLoading.value = true;

      Rx<User?> response = (await AuthController.instance
              .login(emailOrUsernameController.text, passwordController.text))
          .obs;
      if (response.value != null) {
        GetStorage().write('token', response.value!.token);

        Get.offAndToNamed('/tab');
      }
      isLoading.value = false;
    }
  }

  void clearFields() {
    emailOrUsernameController.clear();
    passwordController.clear();
  }

  String? validateEmailOrUsername(String? value) {
    {
      if (value!.isEmpty) {
        return "Email or username can't be empty!";
      } else if (!GetUtils.isEmail(value)) {
        return "Not a valid email address!";
      }
      return null;
    }
  }

  String? validatePassword(String? value) {
    {
      if (value!.isEmpty) {
        return "Password can't be empty!";
      } else if (value.length < 8) {
        return "Password can't be less than 8 characters!";
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';
import 'package:travel_mate/app/global_components/my_text_field.dart';
import 'package:travel_mate/app/modules/views/components/custom_button.dart';
import 'package:travel_mate/app/utils/colors.dart';

import '../Controller/login_controller.dart';

class LoginView extends GetView<LoginController> {
  const LoginView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.w, vertical: 5.w),

                //FORMS START FROM HERE

                child: Form(
                  key: controller.formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      //Main art and logo

                      Center(
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                          'assets/images/login_art.svg',
                          width: 75.w,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 1.h,
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'TravelMate',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Comic Sans Ms',
                            fontSize: 22.5.sp,
                            color: primaryColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 2.h,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'login'.tr,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily:
                              GoogleFonts.poppins(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                                  .fontFamily,
                          fontSize: 15.sp,
                          color: primaryColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 2.h,
                      ),

                      //Username Field

                      MyTextField(
                        textEditingController:
                            controller.emailOrUsernameController,
                        validator: controller.validateEmailOrUsername,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        labelText: 'emailLabel'.tr,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 3.h,
                      ),

                      //Password Field

                      MyTextField(
                        validator: controller.validatePassword,
                        textEditingController: controller.passwordController,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                        labelText: 'passwordLabel'.tr,
                        isPassword: true,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 3.h,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () {},
                            child: Text(
                              'forgot'.tr,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: GoogleFonts.poppins().fontFamily),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 4.h,
                      ),

                      //Login button

                      Obx(
                        () => CustomButton(
                            onTap: controller.login,
                            isLoading: controller.isLoading.value,
                            title: 'login'.tr),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 4.h,
                      ),

                      //Sign in with google button

                      SizedBox(
                        height: 4.h,
                      ),

                      //Not registered yet button

                      Center(
                        child: Text.rich(
                          TextSpan(
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: GoogleFonts.poppins().fontFamily,
                              fontSize: 12.sp,
                              // color: const Color(0xff000000),
                            ),
                            children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                text: 'registerText'.tr,
                              ),
                              TextSpan(
                                recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                  ..onTap = (() {
                                    Get.toNamed('/sign-up');
                                  }),
                                text: 'signup'.tr,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: const Color(0xff0189e2),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          textHeightBehavior: TextHeightBehavior(
                              applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          softWrap: false,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: after trying out some possible reasons, and delaying the call of the run app function by around 500ms I was able to resolve this issue but still not sure what is causing such an error.